# Parcel Bundler gives Content Security Policy Error

Tags: javascript, bundler, content-security-policy, parceljs

Every time I bundle(Parcel) my project I always get a error saying...

`Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:#####/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy`

This forces me to update my connect-src attribute in my meta tag every single time to make it work. But Is there anyway I could avoid this from happening each time I do a new npm run start? or is this how it's suppose to be?

Comment: What is the problem? You loose content of `connect-src` in the meta-tag, or you have a different port number each time? If the last case you can use `connect-src ws://localhost:*`

Comment: Thank you for the solution yes it was the last case. I would mark your comment as the answer but I am not seeing a button to do so